# Rays and optical pathlength minimization

Tags: optics, refraction, geometric-optics

My textbook, *Fundamentals of Photonics, Third Edition*, by Saleh and Teich, says the following in a section on **Planar Boundaries**:

> The relation between the angles of refraction and incidence, $\theta_2$ and $\theta_1$, at a planar boundary between two media of refractive indices $n_1$ and $n_2$ is governed by Snell's law (1.1-3). This relation is plotted in Fig. 1.2-8 for two cases:
>
> $\blacksquare$ *External Refraction* ($n_1 < n_2$). When the ray is incident from the medium of smaller refractive index, $\theta_2 < \theta_1$ and the refracted ray bends away from the boundary.
>
> $\blacksquare$ *Internal Refraction* ($n_1 > n_2$). If the incident ray is in a medium of higher refractive index, $\theta_2 > \theta_1$ and the refracted ray bends toward the boundary.
>
> [image]
>
> The refracted rays bend in such a way as to minimize the optical pathlength, i.e., to increase the pathlength in the lower-index medium at the expense of pathlength in the higher-index medium. In both cases, when the angles are small (i.e., the rays are paraxial), the relation between $\theta_2$ and $\theta_1$ is approximately linear, $n_1 \theta_1 \approx n_2 \theta_2$, or $\theta_2 \approx (n_1/n_2)\theta_1$.

Reading what the authors have said here, and comparing it to figure 1.2-8, when they say that the optical pathlength is *minimized*, they're referring to the pathlength from the origin of the ray to some imaginary vertical line on the $n_2$ medium side, right? is this a correct way to conceptualize the minimization of optical pathlength?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that ray propagation in a homogeneous medium is straight line. Now assume that you are given both the source point in medium 1, say P, and a point Q in medium 2 that lies on the true refracted ray and let $X_0$ be the point on the interface of the two media where the ray refracts. For any point $X$ on the interface form the sum $L[X]=n_1 PX + n_2 XQ$ where $PX$ and $XQ$ are the lengths of the straight line segments in hte respective medium. Fermat' principle states that as $X$ is infinitesimally varied around $X_0$ the *optical path length* $L[X] \ge L[X_0]$

Note too that one can replace the fixed point $Q$ in medium 2 with a given fixed direction and minimize a different optical path length. Fix an arbitrary reference $Z$ and for every straight line in medium 2 project $Z$ unto the line, say $T$ and now measure the optical path length (distance time refractive index) from the fixed $P$ to $T$: $L_1[X] = n_1 PX + n_2 XT$ where now the segment $XT$ is now the fixed direction. Then again the minimum of  $L_1[X]$ as $X$ is varied within an infinitesimal neighborhood of the actual $X_0$ at the interface takes its minimum value with Snell's law! This modification of Fermat's principle is due to Hamilton.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So the ray through the point $X$ on the interface does *not* refract, and the ray through the point $X_0$ on the interface *does* refract?

Comment: It is not quite that a ray through $X$ does no refract, instead that the ray connecting $P$ and $Q$ refracts through $X_0$ and there is another ray that may refract through $X$ but then it does not go through $Q$. You can have any point on the interface refract *some* ray but the one going through from $P$ to $Q$ is when $X=X_0$ and *then* $L[X]=L[X_0+\delta X]$ is minimum when $\delta X=0$ with $X=X_0 + \delta X$ and $\delta X$ is an arbitrary infinitesimal.

Comment: What do you mean by “true refracted ray”?

Comment: By the "true" refracted ray I mean the two straight line segments $PX$ and $XQ$ (or $XT$) along which the ray from $P$ to $Q$ actually propagates, that is when $X=X_0$; for any other $X=X_0+\delta X$ the segments are not true rays, for there is only one ray between two fixed points $P, Q$. Your question was about two semi-infinite homogeneous media joined at a plane and am ignoring now the more general case that you can also have an *infinity* of rays between a pair of points when properly focused.

Comment: Since rays are vectors (straight lines), how can you have the same source $P$ and endpoint $Q$ for two different values $X_0$ and $X$? I was under the impression that each source and point of incidence $X$ leads to a unique endpoint, so I don't understand the situation that you have described in your main post, where $X_0$ and $X \not= X_0$ somehow have the same source $P$ and endpoint $Q$? I was under the impression that this is only possible if $X = X_0$ (that is, the points of incidence are the same).

Comment: have you heard of the concept virtual displacement? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_displacement, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_principle